# Understanding of an example vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be any set over let $K^x$ be set of functions from $X$ to $K$. Then $K^x$ is a vector space over $K$ where

$\left( f+g\right) \left( x\right)=f\left( x\right) +g\left( x\right)$

$\left( \lambda f\right) \left( x\right) =\lambda \left( f\left( x\right) \right)$.

**My question is: What is the $K^x$ (notations of upper x) mean?**

Comment: There must be a typo, the proper notation is $K^X$ and by definition this is the set of maps from $X$ to $K$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Yes. Thanks.